# Cambiar clave en Array en php

Tags: php

¿Como le puedo hacer para cambiar este array en php

```
Array ( [respuestas] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [estatus] => ok [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado [referencia] => 2017071908074881946 [numcelular] => 7717477878 ) ) )
```

a

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [estatus] => ok [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado [referencia] => 2017071908074881946 [numcelular] => 7717477878 ) ) )
```

Solo quiero cambiar el nombre para despue crear un json y pasarlo a un DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar el nuevo "key" con una copia de los datos y luego elimnar el anterior. Asumanos que se llama $myArray :

```
$myArray['data'] = $myArray['respuestas'];

unset($myArray['respuestas']);
```